# GeoServer WFS DescribeFeatureType does not show all attributes

Tags: geoserver, wfs, describe-feature-type

I have a GeoServer 2.12.5 running, which shows this behaviour:

WFS 1.0.0. returns all feature attributes correctly.

https://my-geoserver/workspace/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=workspace:featuretypename

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://my-geoserver/rest/namespaces/workspace">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="https://my-geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="myfeaturetypenameType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="fid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="coordinate" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="num" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="url_ficha" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="flora_faun" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="aves_play" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="cuenc_hidr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="amenazas" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="gobernanza" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="otras_obs" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="pais" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="zona" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="lon" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="lat" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="gfid" nillable="false" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="myfeaturetypename" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="workspace:myfeaturetypenameType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

WFS 1.1.0 and 2.0.0 omit the `name` attribute.

https://my-geoserver/workspaces/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAMES=workspace:myfeaturename

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://my-geoserver/geoserver/rest/namespaces/workspace">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="https://my-geoserver/schemas/gml/2.1.2/feature.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="myfeaturetypenameType">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="fid" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="coordinate" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="num" nillable="true" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="url_ficha" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="flora_faun" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="aves_play" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="cuenc_hidr" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="amenazas" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="gobernanza" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="otras_obs" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="pais" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="zona" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="lon" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="lat" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="gfid" nillable="false" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="myfeaturetypename" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="workspace:myfeaturetypenameType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Is this something related to the specification, i.e. expected behaviour, which I am missing? Or can this be dependent on my setup?

Comment: I managed to reproduce the exact same behavior. Renaming the field "name" to something else helped in my case. Would be nice to know what causes this, but since it works with 1.0, the answer lies somewhere in WFS version differences. I have version 2.19.2 of Geoserver, though.

Comment: Probably related to this https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42660